# Write a program that determines how many vowels and consonants in a string python

Tags: python

Write a program with a function that accepts a string as an argument and returns the number of vowels that the string contains. The application should have another function that accepts a string as an argument and returns the number of consonants that the string contains. The application should let the user enter a string and should display the number of vowels and the number of consonants it contains.

Here is my code I have so far:

```
def main():
   mystr = input('Please enter a string: ')
   mystr.lower()
   index = 0
   vowelSet = set(['a','e','i','o','u'])
   vowels = 0
   consonants = 0

def runVowels(mystr):
    while index < len(mystr):
        if mystr[index] in vowels:
            vowels += 1
            index += 1
        print('This string consists of ' + mystr(vowels) + 'vowels')

def runConsonants(mystr):
    while index < len(mystr):
        if mystr[index] != vowels:
            consonants += 1
            index += 1
        print('This string consists of ' + mystr(consonants) + 'consonants')

main()
```

Where did I go wrong at and am i on the right track?

Comment: What does the code do?  Are you getting an error message, or just bad behavior?

Comment: The code just asks the user to input a string but that's it. I know i'm doing something wrong not sure where i'm doing it wrong though. and if there is code missing.

Comment: Doesn't look like you're executing your `runVowels` or `runConsonants` functions.  You're only defining them, not calling them.

Comment: Okay i changed my code up a bit i think i'm still calling the functions wrong but will keep working at it

Comment: Don't update your question to try to do what the answers suggest. StackOverflow isn't an iterative debugging system, it's meant to provide good, reusable answers to problems that other people might want to search for. If you have a new problem you're stuck on, create a new question (linked to this one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below was tested on python 2.7.3.

1. You need to study about variable scoping, you cannot define a variable in one method and use it in another method.
2. Study a bit about whats the best way to take input from user, sys is a really good library for that

Always, Always initialize your variables before you use them, Have provided comments inline.

```
def main():

   mystr = raw_input("Enter your String:")
   mystr.lower()
   #index = 0, index is useless here
   vowelSet = set(['a','e','i','o','u'])
   #vowels = 0, vowels is useless here
   #consonants = 0, consonants is useless here

   #Either pass vowelSet as argument or define them explicitly in the methods
   runVowels(mystr, vowelSet)
   runConsonants(mystr, vowelSet)

def runVowels(mystr, vowelSet):
    #index, vowels needs to be defined and assigned a default value here
    index = 0
    vowels = 0

    while index < len(mystr):
        if mystr[index] in vowelSet:
            vowels += 1

        # You need to increment index outside of the condition
        index += 1
 print 'This string consists of ', vowels , 'vowels'

def runConsonants(mystr, vowelSet):
    #index, consonants needs to be defined and assigned a default value here
    index = 0
    consonants = 0
    while index < len(mystr):
        if mystr[index] not in vowelSet:
            consonants += 1

        # You need to increment index outside of the condition
        index += 1
    print 'This string consists of ' , consonants , 'consonants'

main()
```

Sample Run:

```
$ python vow.py 
Enter your String:aeeiithy
This string consists of  5 vowels
This string consists of  3 consonants
```

Again, this program only prints number of vowels. If you need number of 'distinct' vowels, it would be a bit different. 
Hope this helps !

Answer (score 6):

You've got multiple problems here.

- While you define functions named `myVowels` and `myConsonants`, you never call them. You probably want to do that at the end of your `main` function.
- Inside `main`, `mystr.lower()` doesn't do anything useful. That function returns a new string, the all-lowercase equivalent to `mystr`, but you don't store that anywhere. Store it somewhere (whether back to `mystr`, or into a new variable) so you can use it.
- Inside `runVowels`, the `index += 1` comes inside the `if` statement. So, as soon as you find a consonant, you're going to pass over the `if`, miss incrementing `index`, and just loop over the same consonant over and over. Dedent that line. (You have this same bug again in `runConsonants`, and the same is true for all of the following bugs.)
- Inside `runVowels`, the `print` call comes inside the `while` statement, so it's going to print the running total once for each letter, instead of just printing the total at the end. Again, dedent one line.
- You create variables named `index`, `vowels` and `vowelsSet` in `main`, which means they're local to that function. You then access variables with those names in `runVowels`, where they don't exist. Each function has its own local namespace. Move those assignments from `main` to `runVowels`—or pass them into `runVowels`, the same way you do with `mystr`.
- You create variables named `vowels` and `vowelsSet`, but then you try to access them as if they were both called `vowels`. Keep things straight, use the right names for the right values.
- I'm not sure what `mystr(vowels)` is supposed to do. You can't call a string like a function. I think you wanted the builtin `str` function here. (However, you may want to look at string formatting, or just look at what happens when you pass multiple arguments to `print`; you rarely need to concatenate strings the way you're doing.)

I won't guarantee that fixing all of these problems will make your code do what you want—it's certainly necessary, but may not be sufficient.

However, hopefully understanding what's wrong with each of these should help you learn how to spot similar problems yourself (not how to avoid them—unless you're the greatest genius in history, you'll be writing bugs like this until the day you die, you'll just get better at testing, debugging, and fixing them).

Comment: Thanks for the input. Still haven't gotten the program to actually run but i'm going over the book looking for solutions. I did change what you suggested though. I think the way I called the functions in the main  could be preventing it from running

Answer (score 0):

You're getting closer. You still have the mysterious `mystr.lower()` inside your loops. You should take it out of the loops, and you need to save the result it returns (the lower-case version of mystr) somewhere, 
eg `mystr = mystr.lower()`. 
I suggest you do that in main() and then pass the lower-case version to your counting functions.

Once you do that, runVowels() will be almost perfect. runConsonants() still needs a little more work. If a character isn't a vowel doesn't mean that it's necessarily a consonant - it could be a number, a punctuation mark, or a space.

It would be more Pythonic if the loops in your functions looped over the string itself, you don't need the index stuff. Check this out in the interpreter:

```
mystr = "This is a TEST string"
for letter in mystr:
    print(letter)
```

Also, the question specifies that each of your counting functions should return a number. So runVowels() and runConsonants() should return their counts to main() and let it take care of the printing.

Answer (score 0):

Don't turn this example into your class ;-)

Checking it out might help you get yours working.

```
def charCounts(mystr):
   mystr = mystr.strip().lower()
   vowels = 0
   cons = 0
   for c in mystr:
        if c in 'aeiou':
            vowels += 1
        elif c >= 'a' and c <= 'z':
            cons += 1
   return vowels, cons

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mystr = input('Please enter a string: ')
    vowels, cons = charCounts(mystr)
    print('This string consists of {0} vowels and {1} consonants'.format(vowels, cons))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Def test_case1(*arg):
arg=eval(input("enter the object:")

     vowels=0
       for x1 in arg:
           if(x1 in("AEIOUaeiou")):
               Vowels+=1
               Print("vowels:",x1)

      consent=0
      for y1 in arg:
          if(y1 not in("AEIOUaeiou")):
              Consents+=1
              print ("consent:",y1):

if(___name__=="__main__"):

      test_case1("arg")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).